# ngx-daterangepicker isnt working on production

Tags: angular

Its working fine with ng serve on local env ,but it not working properly with ng build --prod.(Angular 7)

On local ,my input box,where i used this date picker code look like this

```
<input _ngcontent-c7="" class="cal-input ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" ngxdaterangepickermd="" type="text" ng-reflect-always-show-calendars="false" ng-reflect-show-custom-range-label="true" ng-reflect-linked-calendars="true" ng-reflect-show-clear-button="false" ng-reflect-ranges="[object Object]" ng-reflect-opens="right" ng-reflect-show-cancel="true" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]">
```

On prod,my input box code

```
<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="cal-input ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" ngxdaterangepickermd="" type="text">
```

I dont know what is causing this issue

Comment: input box value is "02-02-2019undefined02-02-2019" in prod

Comment: hello, use the latest version